# Should I be able to boot any ISO with pxelinux?

Tags: boot, iso, pxe, netboot

I have downloaded some `ISO` file for linux (actually from here: http://minimal.linux-bg.org/download/2018/)

The I have configured it with PXE:

```
LABEL minimallinux
MENU LABEL Minimal Linux
KERNEL vmlinuz
INITRD /iso/minimal_linux_live_28-Jan-2018_64-bit_bios.iso
APPEND iso raw
```

and got hang or kernel panic.

I was able to boot a lot of ISO-s this way. And I see on booting computer that kernel is downloaded ok, ISO is downloaded and pritouts starting.

Should I be able to boot any `ISO` this way? If not, then what are requirements for it?

What are "bios", "uefi" and "mixed" types? Isn't ISO just a container of files, which are mounted as r/o filesystem? How it can depend on it?

---

I was able to boot with

```
KERNEL memdisk
```

where `memdisk` is a binary from `syslinux` package. What did I do? Where is Linux kernel then? Was it booted from inside `ISO` on later stages or it `memdisk` is a kernel?

Comment: iso or iso-9660 is a format for a cdrom. The KERNEL specifies a program to be loaded and executed, and the INITRD is loaded into memory and a pointer is given to the KERNEL. Typically you will need a utility rather than a linux kernel to make sense of an iso image.

Comment: if you're using syslinux's gpxelinux.0 or similar, it should be able to boot an iso.  I use that to pxe boot gparted ISOs.  I only use "APPEND iso", not "APPEND iso raw", but I suspect that you may be trying to boot an ISO image meant for an older BIOS system instead of a newer UEFI system.   Try downloading and using the UEFI version....and, at a guess, the mixed version might work for both BIOS and UEFI machines.

Comment: I know this is a little bit old but just in case this is still relevant ... the problem here is the 'KERNEL vmlinuz' line - it should be 'KERNEL memdisk' and the 'raw' option should not be appended.